# Babel & Node : Error after transpiling ((0 , _express.express) is not a function)

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I am writing ES6 in NodeJS env via Babel. So here is my `.babelrc` file :

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2"],
  "plugins": []
}
```

Yep, pretty simple. I'm using npm scripts to launch commands :

```
"build-server": "babel server/lib -d server/dist",
    "build-server:w": "babel server/lib -w -d server/dist",
```

And it works great. Under `server/`, I have a `lib` folder which contains my source code and a `dist` folder with 'babel-code'.

So typically, I can write this :

```
import { ModuleAPI } from './api/moduleAPI';
import { path } from 'path';
import { fs } from 'fs';
import { express } from 'express';
let app = express();
```

which is successfully transpiled to :

```
'use strict';

var _moduleAPI = require('./api/moduleAPI');

var _path = require('path');

var _fs = require('fs');

var _express = require('express');

var app = (0, _express.express)();
```

The issue is, when I execut `node server/dist/server.js`, an error is throwed :

```
var app = (0, _express.express)();
                               ^
TypeError: (0 , _express.express) is not a function
```

I've seen some 'similar' issues :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187535/using-babel-jest-and-get-typeerror-0-createclass3-default-is-not-a-functio
[webpack babel es7 async function error "TypeError: (0 , _typeof3.default) is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949159/webpack-babel-es7-async-function-error-typeerror-0-typeof3-default-is-not)

But I can't get my code works with Babel.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to remove the braces around `express`.

```
import express from 'express';
```

`express` doesn't export an `express` property.

Comment: Mh. I have not searched enough. Thanks.

Comment: Same applies to your other imports now I think about it.