# Babel 6 transform-runtime: $export is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to incorporate Babel's transform-runtime to make my code compatible with IE9. But since integrating it, the code won't even run on Chrome. I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: $export is not a function` on `es6.object.define-property.js:3`. Without the "transform-runtime" line in my .babelrc, everything runs fine. Any ideas?

Here is my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime"
  ],
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ]
}
```

And my `webpack.config.js`:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

var commonsPlugin = new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common.js');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    EventAdmin: './src/event_admin',
    EventRender: './src/event_render'
  },
  output: {
    path: '../public/js2',
    filename: '[name].js' // Template based on keys in entry above
  },
  externals: {
    // require("jquery") is external and available
    //  on the global var jQuery
    'jquery': 'jQuery'
  },
  plugins: [commonsPlugin],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
    ]
  }
};
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the same error and already tried the suggestions available on the thread, but unfortunately without any success. The code can be found here - https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-unixfs-engine/pull/35

Comment: Ted Avery, could you mark @Pierre Wahlgren's answer as correct. He has the most up votes cause it's a good answer that helps

Comment: @silverlight513 It's not the correct answer. Like he said, he has no idea why it works.

Comment: It *is* the correct answer, even if he didn't know why. The reason why it is is that this way you tell Babel not to apply code transforms to everything in the `node_modules` directory (which usually doesn't make sense and is not required, as it is not your code).

Answer (score 48):

Try adding `exclude: /node_modules/` after `loader: 'babel-loader'`. I had the same problem when trying to run the runtime transformer without excluding *node_modules*. I am not aware of the underlying problem, though.

Comment: You guys made my day. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Same problem. Everything goes right after exclude node_modules. Thanks!

Comment: I had `exclude: /\/node_modules\//`, changing that to `exclude: /node_modules/` fixed this.

Comment: I had `exclude: "/node_modules/"`, fixed by changing to `exclude: /node_modules/`

Comment: specifically, the `/node_modules/` exclude *must* be a regex expression and not a string.

Comment: I am still wondering why this could work. How the error happened

Answer (score 23):

Hello I have the same issue and finally found a solution that works for me. See:

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /.js/,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: {
      presets: ['es2015', 'es2017'],
      plugins: [
        ['transform-runtime', {
          helpers: false,
          polyfill: false,
          regenerator: true, }],
        'transform-es2015-destructuring',
        'transform-object-rest-spread',
        'transform-async-to-generator',
        ],
     },
  },
]
```

See the 'transform-runtime' part. I hope this helps.

Comment: I had both the error from the OP and `TypeError: __webpack_require__(...) is not a function` through experimentation.  Here's a [wepack issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4012#issuecomment-280708597) that shows my working `.babelrc` and webpack config.

Comment: Thanks, this also worked for me, using gulp `["transform-runtime", {
          "helpers": false,
          "polyfill": false,
          "regenerator": true }
        ],`

Comment: This says to do opposite - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33979035/1429097
Issue seems similar

Answer (score 8):

You can try replace "exclude" by "include", following the recomendations from [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders).

> Try to prefer "include" when possible...

This worked for me.

```
{
  "test": /\.js/,
  "loader": "babel",
  "include": [path.resolve(__dirname, './src')]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

At first you must installed `babel-plugin-transform-runtime` and then use it like me:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

After it you must add `exclude` key to your `babel-loader` inside `webpack` configuration file:

```
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        }
    ]
}
```

**Attention:** please write `/node_modules/` not `/(node_modules\/)/` or `/node_modules\//`, it's weird but this way works.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to be a problem with running `core-js` files through Babel 6 because Babel 6 no longer converts `require('something')` to `require('something').default` as Babel 5 did. I even tried running it through this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports but no matter what I did, it wouldn't correct the require statements properly. I ultimately just had to exclude the `core-js` and various Babel related files from being processed by the `babel-loader` by setting the `exclude` property to this:

`[
  /node_modules\/babel-/m,
  /node_modules\/core-js\//m,
  /node_modules\/regenerator-runtime\//m
]`

**As a side note**, I hadn't reinstalled my `node_modules` since converting to Babel 6 and that caused the same issue but for some other mysterious reason.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who are using webpack, make sure to no include the `node_modules` folder with the following in your webpack configuration file:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      // With this line, make sure you only include your javascript
      // source files
      include: [ path.resolve(__dirname, './src') ],
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['env'],
          plugins: ['transform-runtime']
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you [install](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-runtime/#installation) also the babel-runtime?

I just installed both and added the plugin in the .babelrc and it worked out.

Comment: Yes I did, do I need to do anything special to use it? I don't reference it anywhere, I understood that using the "transform-runtime" plugin in.babelrc would use it automatically.