# Babel 7/Webpack Why Do I need to use loose: true in preset env?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I am compiling my app using babel 7 and webpack. I have a monorepo. You can see with the configuration below that I am using the preset `@babel/env`. When I did not have `loose: true` configured within that preset and tried running the app an error would be thrown in the console:

`(0 , _typeof3.default) is not a function`

This was not helpful. It was luck that I added `loose: true` and fixed it. Anyone know why this would fix the issue?

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  if (api) {
    api.cache(() => process.env.NODE_ENV);
  }
  return {
    sourceType: 'unambiguous',
    presets: [
      [
        '@babel/env',
        {
          // **** ADDING THIS NEXT LINE FIXED IT ****
          loose: true,
          useBuiltIns: 'usage',
          modules: false,
          targets: {
            browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 11'],
          },
        },
      ],
      '@babel/react',
    ],
    plugins: [
      '@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types',
      '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
      ...stagePlugins,
    ],
  };
};
```

Comment: You can apply `loose: true` only to transform-runtime plugin instead of global. [That plugin probably causes the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949159/webpack-babel-es7-async-function-error-typeerror-0-typeof3-default-is-not). Also check that you excludes node_modules in loader..

Comment: There's not a `loose` option for @babel/plugin-transform-runtime. Only preset-env. I want transform runtime for the benefits it gives and for regenerator runtime that doesn't seem to be included otherwise.

Comment: Hmm.. Did you try option `useESModules: true`?